# How find all possible values of $a_{2015}$ for $a_2 = 5$, $a_{2014} = 2015$, and $a_n=a_{a_{n-1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_i)_{i\in \Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence of nonnegative integers such that $a_2 = 5$, $a_{2014} = 2015$, and $a_n=a_{a_{n-1}}$ for all other positive $n$.  How find all possible values of $a_{2015}$?

Comment: $a_n = a_{a_{n-1}}$ does not have to hold for $n = 2, 2014$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a an exercise of USA Mathematical Talent Search (Academic Year 2014–2015) and the solutions can be found [here](http://www.usamts.org/Solutions/Solutions_26_1.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$a(5)=a(a(4))=a(a(a(3)))=a(a(a(a(2))))=a(a(a(5)))$$

Therefore $$a(3)=a(5)=a(7)=a(9)=\cdots=a(2013)=a(2015)=\cdots$$

Therefore $$a(4)=a(6)=a(8)=a(10)=\cdots=a(2012)=a(2014)=\cdots=2015$$

Now, $a(2)=5$ and $a(4,6,\cdots,2014,\cdots)=2015$.

Let $a(3,5,7,\cdots,2015,\cdots)=q$.

If $q=1$, then $a(2,4,6,\cdots)=a(a(1))=5$, contradition.

If $q=3,5,7,\cdots, 2015,\cdots$, then $a(2014)=a(a(2013))=a(q)=a(2015)=q$, hence $a(2015)=q=2015$

If $q=2$, then $a(4,6,8,\cdots,)=a(2)=5$, contradition.

If $q=4, 6, 8, \cdots$, then $a(4,6,8,\cdots)=a(a(3,5,7,\cdots))=a(4,6,8,\cdots)$, which is ok.